# How to make synchronize in node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make it simply synchronize concatenated string which starts before the function and ends after the function. Please see the code snippet and make it simple to get the output like:

```
<products>
<proudct_name>Product1</product_name>
<proudct_name>Product2</product_name>
<proudct_name>Product3</product_name>
</products>
```

Any positive reply will be appreciated.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : DB_USER,
      password : DB_PASS,
      database : DB_NAME,
});

connection.connect();

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_product limit 0,3');

var str = '<products>';

query.on('result', function (row) {
    str += '<product_name>'row.product_name + '</product_name>';
});

str += '</products>';

console.log(str);
```

Comment: There's probably another event type sent on completion, no ? Or is `on("result"` called with the entire result set ? What's query1 ?

Comment: are you using node-mysql https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/ package?

Comment: Now is it make sense?

Comment: look in to this https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#streaming-query-rows for more details you will have to write a processRow function that will create new string and at the end you can get the string required. I am not able to answer this question as I guess it has been put on hold.

Comment: Place your str+=... and console .. in query.on('end', function(){ // here });

Comment: I can't place my console inside query.on because I need to use the final string to another operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a promises like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) to write synchronous looking/behaving asynchronous code. 
With Q, you would write the above like

```
var str = '<=========';
var defer = Q.defer();
query1.on('result', function (row) {
  defer.resolve(row.company_name + ',');
});

defer.promise.then(function(row){
  var str = "<=======" + row.company + "====>";
  console.log(str);
});
```

You can use a timeout technique as well. Promises are better and are in the [ES6](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-promise-objects) specification for integration with upcoming javascript.

As per comments, more modern promises frameworks exists with more features. [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisemethodfunction-fn---function) provides a nice way to promisify existing functions much easily.

Comment: Q is an ancient promise implementations, by the way. OP might want to use something modern.

Comment: Also, your usage of Q itself is mostly incorrect, you probably meant to do `defer.promise.then` without that `Q.when` (which should just be `Q(` btw.

Comment: I'm not sure using promises here help to "just make it simple".

Comment: I am getting <=======undefined====>

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I have improved the answer a bit.

Comment: But this does not brings my result. Please can you explain so that I can make it simple.