# How to make it simple in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make it simply synchronize concatenated string which starts before the function and ends after the function. Please see the code snippet and make it simple to get the output like:

```
<start_xml>
<products>
    <proudct_name>Product1</product_name>
    <proudct_name>Product2</product_name>
    <proudct_name>Product3</product_name>
</products>
<companies>
    <company_name>Product1</company_name>
    <company_name>Product2</company_name>
    <company_name>Product3</company_name>
</companies>
</start_xml>
```

Any positive reply will be appreciated.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : DB_USER,
      password : DB_PASS,
      database : DB_NAME,
});

connection.connect();

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_product limit 0,3');

var str = '<start_xml>';

str += '<products>';

query.on('result', function (row) {
    str += '<product_name>' + row.product_name + '</product_name>';
});

str += '</products>';

str += '<companies>';

var query1 = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_employee limit 0,3');
query1.on('result', function (row) {
    str += '<company_name>' + row.company_name + '</company_name>';
});
str += '</companies>';

str = '</start_xml>';

console.log(str);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make synchronize in node js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821101/how-to-make-synchronize-in-node-js)

Comment: Your JS has invalid syntax on the `str +=` line. Also, you can't add the closing tag until the async processing has finished.

Comment: I need proper solution. But didn't get any. Any proper solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try using a callback function in the call to connection.query()
http://www.codediesel.com/nodejs/querying-mysql-with-node-js/

Comment: It looks like you want to generate an XML from js objects. Try to find an XML serializer for node.js. There are several, one of them: https://github.com/davidcalhoun/jstoxml

Answer (score 2):

Updated to last edit, but it's bad practice to sync code in such way, called callback hell. Better use [promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-promise) or [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async).
You can pass a callback function to query and iterate in it, like this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: DB_USER,
  password: DB_PASS,
  database: DB_NAME,
});

connection.connect();

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_product limit 0,3', function(error, results, fields) {
  var str = '<start_xml>';
  str += '<products>';

  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    str += '<product_name>' + results[i].product_name + '</product_name>';
  }

  str += '</products>';

  var query1 = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_employee limit 0,3', function(error, results, fields) {
      str += '<companies>';
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        str += '<company_name>' + results[i].company_name + '</company_name>';
      }
      str += '</companies>';
      str += '</start_xml>';
      console.log(str);
  });

});
```

More are in [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries).

Comment: My requirement is generate a whole xml by getting data from various tables. I can not do it for a single table. I have 3 tables and from that 3 tables I need to create a xml. which I need to send another server.

Comment: There are several ways: either make a one SELECT statement with joining tables or use async.js to make three arrays and then work with them. https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

Comment: Please its not like that, I need to start the xml string before exploring first table and then inside that tables loop, concatenated the string with the next tables data. Its a simple concatenated string way to logic which is not happened in node.

Comment: Node.js slightly differs from other traditional web languages like php. Statements are not executed in the way, they've written in code. That's why you need first grab data, then sync to have all three tables and then build your xml.

Comment: Please see the code once, I have made some modification which will explain what I wanted.

Comment: Try to see duplicated answer, it's lead to right way you want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821101/how-to-make-synchronize-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to remember these queries will be run concurrently, so you have to either wait for the end of the first one before making the second query (but that would be inefficient), or write a function that will collect the results once both have finished.

The second way is fairly easy once you get used to the slightly different way of thinking about it.

```js
connection.connect();

var productsFinished = false;
var productsQuery = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_product limit 0,3');
var productsStr = '';
productsQuery.on('result', function (row) {
    str += '<product_name>' + row.product_name + '</product_name>';
});

productsQuery.on('end', function() {
  productsFinished = true;
  complete()  
})

var companiesFinished = false;
var companiesStr = '';
var companiesQuery = connection.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_employee limit 0,3');

companiesQuery.on('result', function (row) {
    companiesStr += '<company_name>' + row.company_name + '</company_name>';
});

companiesQuery.on('end', function() {
  companiesFinished = true;
  complete();
});


var complete = function(){
  if(productsFinished && companiesFinished){
    var str = '<start_xml>';
    str += '<products>';
    str += productsStr;
    str += '</products>;

    str += '<companies>';
    str += companiesStr;
    str += '</companies>;

    str += '</start_xml';

    console.log(str);
  }
}
```

Notice you also have to listen for `end` event in both queries, to know when all the rows have been already returned.